# What is the Difference Between Rule (->) and RuleDelayed (:>)?

Tags: evaluation, replacement, expression-manipulation, broken-code

I am new to Mathematica so this question may seem rudimentary. Sorry for that! :)

I want to implement the well-known property of Kronecker's Delta

$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} a_i \delta_{ij}=a_j,\quad 1 \le j \le n$$

So I wrote the following code

```
KroDelProp[Eq_] := Module[{R, c, i, j, a, b},
  R = Inactive[Sum][c_*KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], {i_, a_, b_}] :> (c /. i -> j);
  Eq /. R
  ]
Eq = Inactive[Sum][a[i]*KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, n}]
KroDelProp[Eq]
(* a[j] *)
```

So everything looks fine. But when I use `Rule` instead of `RuleDelayed` in `KroDelProp` then I get

```
KroDelProp[Eq_] := Module[{R, c, i, j, a, b},
  R = Inactive[Sum][c_*KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], {i_, a_, b_}] -> (c /. i -> j);
  Eq /. R
  ]
Eq = Inactive[Sum][a[i]*KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, n}]
KroDelProp[Eq]
(* a[i] *)
```

I read the documentation but I couldn't find out what is happening here!

Can someone shed some light on this? :)

---

I found reading [this documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) very useful. Hope that it helps the future readers of this post too.

Comment: I invite you to read the documentation that the first sentence could not be more explicit.

[Rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) "represents a rule that transforms _lhs_ to _rhs_."
[RuleDelayed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) "represents a rule that transforms _lhs_ to _rhs_, evaluating rhs only after the rule is used."

Comment: @physicien: I read that but I couldn't find why this happens! Why the evaluation of RHS of the rules effects the output here?

Comment: @physicien: Can you tell what happens in each of the codes step by step?

Comment: @physicien: I had a typo. I mean that the output is $a[i]$ or $a[j]$ in each case.

Comment: Try `x = 17; {y -> x, y :> x}`

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think the problem is in `-> (c /. i -> j)`. I think it's because Rule tries to evaluate directly instead of waiting to be used, so as there is nothing to evaluate, it returns the value it had previously.

Comment: @JohnDoty: Thanks. :) Can you kindly write an answer? :) I will be so thankful if you address what happens in each of the codes above. :) In fact, why the outputs differ?

Comment: @H.R. I think a nice simple example of this is as follows--



`rule={a -> Print["a Evaluated"], b :> Print["b Evaluated"]};`


and


`b/.rule`

evaluate that and see what happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to highlight the differences is to isolate the substitution rules you constructed in each case. See what the following rules evaluate to:

```
(* Rule *)
Inactive[Sum][c_*KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], {i_, a_, b_}] -> (c /. i -> j)
```

[image: immediate]

```
(* RuleDelayed *)
Inactive[Sum][c_*KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], {i_, a_, b_}] :> (c /. i -> j)
```

[image: delayed]

You can clearly see that in the first case (simple `Rule`), the right hand side of the rule is immediately evaluated; in that case `c` does not contain `i` so the second replacement in RHS doesn't apply, and the RHS just evaluates to `c`. When you apply this substitution rule, `c` matches `a[i]` in the expression, so that's what's returned.

With `RuleDelayed` evaluation of the right hand side is delayed until *after a match has been found*. In this case, `c` matches to `a[i]`; the right hand side then evaluates to `a[i] /. i -> j`, which produces the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. :) I am happy now! :D

Comment: @H.R. Glad it helped! Your question provides a nice practical example of the difference in behavior between `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`.

Answer (score 2):

It's always useful to see what the fragments of your code do. Compare the result of:

```
Inactive[Sum][c_*KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], {i_, a_, b_}] :> (c /. i -> j)
```

With:

```
Inactive[Sum][c_*KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], {i_, a_, b_}] -> (c /. i -> j)
```

Note also that localizing the names of patterns with `Module` does nothing, and there's no need to name your rule. And then, why not pattern match in your definition, deconstruct your argument there?

```
KroDelProp[Inactive[Sum][c_*KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], {i_, a_, b_}]] := c /. i -> j
KroDelProp[Inactive[Sum][a[i]*KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, n}]]

(* a[j] *)
```

`Module` is rarely useful. It's usually a symptom that you could factor your code better.