# Cannot get column heading to display

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I'm trying to generate simple Row-Column headings for the Josephus survivor problem, but I can't get the column heading "Survivor" to display.  As far as I can tell, I'm dong what is required from the documentation and I suspect I'm doing something trivially wrong but I just can't see it.

I got a workaround by using `Grid`, `Table` and then prepending a `{"","Survivor"}` pair, but it's hardly elegant.

```
survivor[n_] := Range[n] //. {a_, b_, z___} -> {z, a} // First
survivor /@ Range[5] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {Range[5], {"Survivor"}}] &
(*  
1|1
2|1
3|3
4|1
5|3
*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After modifying your function slightly:

```
SetAttributes[survivor, Listable];
survivor[n_Integer] := First[Range[n] //. {a_, b_, z___} :> {z, a}]
```

here is how to get the table you want:

```
TableForm[{survivor[Range[5]]} // Transpose, TableHeadings -> {Range[5], {"Survivor"}}]
```

[image: output]

In a nutshell: `TableForm[]` needs a two-dimensional list, and you were trying to feed it a one-dimensional one (compare `Length[Dimensions[survivor[Range[5]]]]` and `Length[Dimensions[{survivor[Range[5]]}]]`).

Comment: thx - the 1D vs 2D hint has given me something to chew on.  On a side note - I'm still learning about -> vs :> is there anything i should note about your use of :> rather than -> when you modified my original function? AFAIK there's no change in behaviour or is it needed for the Listable attribute?

Comment: @Joe, on the use of `Rule[]` (`->`) vs. `RuleDelayed[]` (`:>`), see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154066) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111051).