# Monitoring Plot3D with a given number of plotpoints

Tags: plotting, monitoring

I have to do a `Plot3D` of a given function which takes very long, so I would like to have an idea of how long it would be. I am looking for the **simplest** way to monitor this.

Here is my code (well not exactly the one I use but I made a simpler example) :

```
H2[x_] := If[x != 0, If[x != 1, (-x)*Log[x] - (1 - x)*Log[1 - x], 0], 0]
Si[Theta_] := H2[Cos[Theta/2]^2]
kb = 1; 
WextMaxOuiDegenBruitTh[T_, ΔI_] := (-kb)*T*ΔI
ηOuiDegenBruitTh[T_, ΔI_] := WextMaxOuiDegenBruitTh[T, ΔI]/Abs[ΔI]

Plot3D[ηOuiDegenBruitTh[Theta, ΔI], {Theta, 0, Pi/2}, {ΔI, -Log[2], 0}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{Theta, ΔI}, -Si[Theta] < ΔI < 0], PlotPoints -> 10]
```

As you can see I gave the `PlotPoints` parameter in my Plot3D so maybe there is a way to tell Mathematica to use the number of points it will have to compute on the plot to make a progress bar from it. But I don't know how to do that.

---

**[EDIT]** As suggested in the comment of the answer below, I can use `EvaluationMonitor` to help me. However, I don't understand something. I changed my Plot3D line by replacing it with this for the example (all the code before is unchanged).

```
Plot3D[ηOuiDegenBruitTh[Theta, ΔI], {Theta, 0, Pi/2}, {ΔI, -Log[2], 0}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
 EvaluationMonitor -> Print["x"]]
```

As written in the documentation, I should have 20*20 points in this calculation, so 400 calculations in the end.

But when I run this line Mathematica only output "x" 3 times. So it is like Mathematica only did 3 calculations and not 400.

My problem is linked to the fact I probably misunderstood how `EvaluationMonitor` works, but I don't know where I am wrong!

---

**[EDIT for MarcoB]**: My exact line is :

```
Monitor[
  Plot3D[
   ηOuiDegenBruitTh[Theta, ΔI], {Theta,0, Pi/2}, {ΔI, -Log[2], 0}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0, EvaluationMonitor :> (x = x + 1)
  ], 
  ProgressIndicator[x, {0, 200^2}]
]
```

Comment: Note: `EvaluationMonitor` requires delayed rules, `:>` instead of `->`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform indeed now i think it works. Just to understand (i'm not sure to really understand the help page for :>), what does it exactly do in my example ? I know it is linked to a delay but with the -> what did the code do in this specific example ?

Comment: see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111051/34893

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform one little extra question : with PlotPoints->100 for my plot depending of two variables, mathematica doesn't use 100^2 points but 200^2. Isn't it supposed to use 100 sample points in each direction ? So 100 in x and 100 in y then 100*100 ? Why 200*200 ?

Comment: Hmm good question. I don't really know off the top of my head, but I'll think about it.

Comment: @StarBucK Have you tried to set `MaxRecursion -> 0` as well? Note that `PlotPoints` sets how many *initial* sample points to use, before they are refined by internal adaptive procedures. `MaxRecursions` controls these internal procedures.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes I have this option. I do another edit to show the exact line I have.

Comment: @MarcoB do you think it could be something like by direction it is like x and -x are considered as two different directions ?

Comment: @StarBucK It turns out that the extra points are due to the calculation of vertex normals for the surface. See also: [Why does Plot3D appear to traverse the points twice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163624/27951). This seems really important in fact, and I wish the documentation mentioned it explicitly, since **three quarters** of the time spent in `Plot3D` with a non-trivial function seem to be due to these extra calculations. You can turn that off using `NormalsFunction -> None`. This may affect visual properties of the graphic, so test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Table[{j,
       AbsoluteTiming[Plot3D[\[Eta]OuiDegenBruitTh[Theta, \[CapitalDelta]I], {Theta, 0, Pi/2}, {\[CapitalDelta]I, -Log[2], 0}, RegionFunction -> Function[{Theta, \[CapitalDelta]I}, -Si[Theta] < \[CapitalDelta]I < 0], PlotPoints -> j]][[1]]
      }
, {j, 10, 200, 10}]

Fit[%, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x]
Show[ListPlot[%%], Plot[%, {x, 0, 200}]]
```

[image]

You can use the `Fit`ted formula to estimate how long it will take to plot your function to any desired number of points. Extrapolating can be misleading though, so use at your own risk.

If you also want to see the progress bar while the plot is being completed, you can use any of the options in [How to create a progress bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5978/34893). For example, using the very first piece of code by [Brett Champion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/69), I get

```
count = 0;
Monitor[
        Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> (Pause[.1]; (count++)),
        PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0]
, Row[{ProgressIndicator[count, {1, 100}], count}, " "]]
```

Here I plotted a `Sin` function for simplicity, but it is trivial to adapt this to your 3d function. I leave this to you.

Comment: Note: I fitted the data to a cubic formula because that's what the log-log plot seemed to suggest. If you calculate more points, you will be able to convince yourself that my guess is correct, or find a better one otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So here if I understand well you made a code that once the calculation is ended give you the time occured for this calculation. And from it you try to predict how long it will take for longer calculations. What I would like to do if it is possible is to have a progress bar *during* the ongoing computation. The progress bar could use the fact we ask for the Plot3D 10 plotPoints (so in theory mathematica knows how much steps are remaining, and it "could" make a progress bar from it). But I don't know if it is possible in practice

Comment: Sure: use `EvaluationMonitor` together with any of the answers in [How to create a progress bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5978/34893). (You will have to use `MaxRecursion -> 0` to make sure `Plot3D` uses exactly `PlotPoints` points, and no more).

Comment: I edited my message, I still don't get something.